# Convert LINQ query to WPF Label Content

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have problem with to load Label Content from Linq query. In WPF i have:

```
<Label Name="firstEvent" />
```

and in class:

```
firstEvent.Content =(
from wydarzenia in atmaEntites.Wydarzenia
where wydarzenia.idWydarzenia==59
select new
{
wydarzenia.Obiekty.nazwa,
}
).First().ToString();
```

This code return **{nazwa = nazwaObiektu}** but i would like the code to return **nazwaObiektu**

Comment: `firstEvent.Content = atmaEntites.Wydarzeni.First(w => w.idWydarzenia == 59).Obiekty.nazwa;` As a note, in WPF you would usually use a TextBlock to show text, not a Label.

Comment: It's work! Great, but it is possible write in Linq instead lambda?

Comment: Just removing `new {` and `}` is more efficient.